# "We have detected a strange activity from this IP address" message

Tags: support, system-message, read-only

At 15:04 UTC, during the [Read-only test - August 1, 2015](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/125387022934/read-onlu-test-august-1-2015), trying to open my Stack Overflow profile page I received a message saying something like

> "We have detected a strange activity from this IP address"

Only text: no style, no topbar, zilch. It has happened only once.

I work and use Stack Overflow in different libraries scattered in four cities, so my public IP address may be shared by other Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange users.

What I ask is:

- Do the various background processes that control  the compliance with
  rules, take into account the public or private address of my PC? Was
  the above message talking about my public or private IP address?
- Was the above message somehow caused by the Read-only test? Or some misbehavior of some users has caused it?
- Should I worry about some retaliation from some user? Although I have some limitations in the language, I can assert that I have never offended anyone.

I love this network, my graduation thesis was a project almost identical to the idea of Stack Overflow, and I don't want either to give or cause any problems of any kind.

**Note:** As you can see [on my Stack Overflow reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4120911?tab=reputation), on that day I had not received either upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: Um, sorry to point this out, but you overformatted your post. It feels like riding on a bumpy road and it's distracting from your content. Instead, use footnotes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it was caused by that read-only test. The new Denver IP range didn't get added and it briefly rate limited all traffic to the network. The error was fixed after about 5 minutes, but not before about 80 people emailed us about the problem. ;)

So you have nothing to worry about. It was completely an error on our end.

Comment: Were those 80 emails within that 5 minute interval? If so, you could ditch all logging and monitoring functionality and use e-mail instead ... ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, but what IP is taken into account to trace me? Private or public? As I said, I work in many libraries and I worry about what could happen if I upvote/downvote a question that a user posted with the same public IP 5 minutes or one week before. I just want to know if an event of this kind may be considered a suspicious behavior.

Comment: @CliffBurton There is no reason to worry about something like that. The specific block you hit is solely for a massive number of requests coming from an IP in a short amount of time. Your actions on the site are not considered.